# Serverless Node.js Project Structure

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, tdd, mocha.js, serverless-framework

I am building a RESTful API with the serverless framework to run on AWS (API Gateway + Lambda + DynamoDB). It's my first Node project and my first serverless production project and I have no idea how to structure it. So far I have the following

   `|--Functions
   |-----Function1
   |--------InternalModule
   |-----Function2
   |-----Function3
   |--------InternalModule
   |-----Function4
   |--Shared
   |-----Module1
   |-----Module2
   |-----Module3
   |--Tests
   |-----Functions
   |--------Function1
   |-----------InternalModule
   |--------Function2
   |-----------InternalModule
   |--------Function3
   |-----------InternalModule
   |--------Function4
   |-----------InternalModule
   |-----Modules
   |--------Module1
   |-----------InternalModule
   |--------Module2
   |-----------InternalModule
   |--------Module3
   |-----------InternalModule`

I keep my API endpoints (Lambda handlers) in Functions. Some of them have internal modules which they only use and there are some who use modules from Shared. I want to have unit tests for all my modules - inner and shared as well as API testing on the lambda functions. I am using mocha and chai and want to integrate everything in a pipeline which on a git push runs the linters and tests and if they are successful deploy the API to the appropriate stage. The problem is that in order to test each module I have to have chai as a local node module in every folder where I have a test file and reference the modules to be tested by a relative path. In most cases it looks really ugly because of the nesting. If I want to test an internal module from 

`Tests/Functions/Function1/InternalModule`

and I require it on top of the test like so 

`require('../../../../Tests/Functions/Function1/InternalModule')`
 + I have to install chai in every folder so it's reachable. The same goes for mocha and all the dependencies needed for the test and I haven't even mentioned configuration. The main idea I am now considering is weather or not I should bring all modules to a folder called modules and require them when needed - worst case 

`from Functions/Function1
require('../../Modules/Module1')`
 
Also keep the test files in the module folder and run them inside, but that would require the assertion library installed in every folder. I've read about npm link and symlinks but I want to keep track of what dependencies each folder has so I can install them on the CI environment after the clean project is downloaded from GitHub where I can't do links (or I've got the whole concept wrong?)

If anyone can suggest a better solution I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

the way Node uses require is so much more than I thought!

> First, Node.js looks to see if the given module is a core module - Node.js comes with many modules compiled directly into the executable binary (ex. http, fs, sys, events, path, etc.). These core modules will always take precedence in the loading algorithm.
>
> If the given module is not a core module, Node.js will then begin to search for a directory named, "node_modules". It will start in the current directory (relative to the currently-executing Javascript file in Node) and then work its way up the folder hierarchy, checking each level for a node_modules folder.

[read more here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)

I will try out Putting all modules in a separate folder each with it's own Folder prefixed with FunctionName_ so I know where each module is used, and the test file + package.json file. Then if I need a module I can require it from the functions with shallow nesting which would look not so bad:

```
from Functions/Function1

require('module-1');
```

with package.json

```
"dependencies":{
    "module-1":"file:../../Modules/Function1_Module1"
}
```

and have a separate folder Shared where I keep the shared Modules.
I am still open for better ideas!